# How do I use ActionCable client in react static page for the Rails5(API mode) app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, actioncable

I am developing now Streaming API with Rails5 api mode, for React website.
That use it in notification functions.

I'm in below's env:

```
<server side>
rails: v5.1.5
ruby: 2.4.2

<client side>
"react": "^15.5.4",
"react-dom": "^15.5.4",
"react-router": "^2.7.0",
"actioncable": "^5.1.5",
```

Server side code:
**app/channels/notifications_channel.rb**

```
class NotificationsChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "notifications"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end
```

**development.rb**

```
config.action_cable.url = "ws://localhost:3000/cable"
```

**application.rb**

```
# websocket
config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins = [
    # Local address of our RoR server
    'http://localhost:3000',
    # Local address we use for our React standalone client
    'http://localhost:8000',
    'chrome-extension://pfdhoblngboilpfeibdedpjgfnlcodoo'
]
ActionCable.server.config.disable_request_forgery_protection = true
```

**routes.rb**

```
mount ActionCable.server => '/cable'
```

**xxx.rb**

```
ActionCable.server.broadcast('notifications', notification: @notification)
```

Client side:

```
componentDidMount () {
  this.createSocket()
}

createSocket = () => {
  let App = {};
  App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer('ws://localhost:3000/cable');

  let subscription = App.cable.subscriptions.create({channel:'NotificationsChannel'}, {
    connected : () => {},
    disconnected : () => {},
    received : (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }
  });
  console.log(subscription)
};
```

And so, this is server side console

```
Started GET "/cable" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-02 13:37:30 +0800
Started GET "/cable/" [WebSocket] for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-03-02 13:37:30 +0800
Successfully upgraded to WebSocket (REQUEST_METHOD: GET, HTTP_CONNECTION:Upgrade, HTTP_UPGRADE: websocket)
NotificationsChannel is transmitting the subscription confirmation
NotificationsChannel is streaming from notifications
```

I am referring this website https://www.npmjs.com/package/actioncable and https://blog.heroku.com/real_time_rails_implementing_websockets_in_rails_5_with_action_cable this one.

BUT the `data`  is not displayed in client console.
How do I change code?

Comment: You have to call  xxx.rb in order to broadcast your notification. You must be subscribed otherwise you will never receive it.

Comment: @GorillaApe Thank you for comment.
But  No matter how much I try exec rake task for call xxx.rb, It never receive any data.

Comment: I dont know your rails config but if you call it from another process you need a sync adapter eg: redis default async wont work

Comment: Thank you @GorillaApe It helped!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GorillaApe

I solved this problem.
It is by setting about `cable.yml` .
`aysnc` doesn't work in this case. `redis` is better as adapter.

this is my `cable.yml` now:

```
development:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379

test:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379

production:
  adapter: redis
  url: redis://localhost:6379
  channel_prefix: api_notification_production
```